# How to play songs in background using MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: rubymotion, mpmusicplayercontroller

My program is working fine when it is in the foreground, but whenever it goes to background it is stops working.

```
@musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.iPodMusicPlayer
```

I am using "applicationMusicPlayer", not "iPodMusicPlayer". Why doesn't it work when it's in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The applicationMusicPlayer doesn't support play music on the background. You can use AVAudioPlayer to play music. In this case you should manage Audio Session for you application.
An example how can it look on the Objective-C ...

```
- (void)playMusic {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"music" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [audioPlayer play];
}
```